# Creating ellipses on a subset of data with different color scale with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a scatterplot where I highlight a subset of points with an ellipse and points, while the rest of the data is plotted as text. I'm able to plot the correct points and ellipses, but the color scale gets added to the overall color scale of the plot, and I would like it to stand out more as its own scale, if that makes sense. Here's a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(345)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=64, min=1, max=20), nrow=64))
df$PC2 <- (runif(n=64, min=1, max=20))
colnames(df) <- c("PC1", "PC2")
df$time <- rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4"), 16)
df$genotype <- rep(c("wt", "mut"), each = 32)
df$treatment <- rep(c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 8), rep("C", 8), rep("D", 8)), 2)
df$sample.id <- c(LETTERS[1:26], paste0("A",LETTERS[1:26]), paste0("B", LETTERS[1:12]))
df$genotype_time <- paste0(df$treatment, "_", df$time)

ggplot(df, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) +
  geom_text(dat = df,
            aes(label=sample.id,
                color = sample.id),
            alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_point(data = subset(df, treatment == "A"),
             aes(group = genotype_time,
                 color = genotype_time),
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_ellipse(data = subset(df, treatment == "A"),
               aes(color = genotype_time,
                   group = genotype_time),
               geom = "polygon", 
               alpha = 0.5,
               fill = NA,
               show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image: Plot1]

You can see that I'm trying to just add ellipses highlighting treatment group A and the data associated with the timepoints 1-4, but they all appear orange and are grouped into the sample color scale. Is there a way to get these to behave separately? This gets me close to what I want for the ellipses, except the dots are still orange-ish and I don't want the ellipses to be filled (ideally the dots would match the color of the associated ellipse):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) +
  geom_text(dat = df,
            aes(label=sample.id,
                color = sample.id),
            alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_point(data = subset(df, treatment == "A"),
             aes(group = genotype_time,
                 color = genotype_time),
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_ellipse(data = subset(df, treatment == "A"),
               aes(fill = genotype_time),
               geom = "polygon", 
               alpha = 0.2)
```

[image: Plot 2]

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From a data visualization perspective, it is hopeless to expect that color-coding 60+ points with different colors will be in any way useful, particularly if you are already labelling them. This adds nothing to your plot but confusion. You should leave the labelled points as dark gray or black, and use color only to highlight the points and ellipses you want to emphasise.